# Уникальные записи в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть бд mysql, в ней таблица, в таблице столбик (называется qwerty). В столбике забиты значения, которые вроде бы уникальны, но охота проверить, так ли это. Как это сделать?

P.S. я не имею ввиду сравнивание 2х бд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select qwerty, count(*) from table group by qwerty
```

придумал запросик красивее

```
select qwerty, count from (SELECT qwerty, count(*) as count FROM table  group by qwerty) where count >1
```

выведет значения, которых больше 1ого

Comment: $zapros = mysql_query("select qwerty, count from (SELECT qwerty, count(*) as count FROM table group by name_from) where count >1");

    while($massiv == mysql_fetch_assoc($zapros)) { echo $massiv["qwerty"]; }

выдает ошибку. еще, не мнего не догнал, что значит "name_from". с поставленным на это место qwerty - то же ошибка.

Comment: поправил, там надо qwerty, и вместо table - имя твоей таблици

Comment: table - понятное дело заменил. спасибо разобрался.

Comment: Хоть PHP и ужОс, но не нужно так называть переменные (zapros), это-же не 1С, LOL

Comment: Чем вас PHP так не устроил? =)

Answer (score 3):

[[@Gorets](/users/3608/gorets)](/users/3608/gorets), а зачем select внутри select-а ? Можно же проще:

```
SELECT `qwerty`, COUNT(`qwerty`) cnt FROM `table` GROUP BY `qwerty` HAVING cnt > 1
```

Comment: да я не сомневался, что мой вариант с 2мя селектами "корявый", просто давно не занимался базами потому некоторые фокусы призабылись..

Answer (score 1):

а не проще воспользоватся

SELECT DISTINCT (`qwerty`) From tablename

а результат сравнить с общим количеством записей

Comment: Это не покажет, какие именно записи дублируются.

Comment: ту так в вопрос стоит - проверить уникальны ли записи в столбце) на счет вывода их никто не говорит

Comment: и как ты их проверишь таким запросом?

Answer (score 0):

гг :) А можно еще попытаться подставить стрибут UNIQUE .... хотя, зависит от того, что за тип данных храним в поле :)

Comment: нет, не даст нужной информации, просто выведет уникальные значения